# SP2010 Reset all subsites to inherit masterpage using c#

Tags: master-page, site-collection, sub-site, feature-receiver

I'm creating a site feature reciever which sets a custom master page on the root web. I would also like the master page set on the root to be inherit to all the subsites. 
What is the most elegant way to ensure this (using .NET)?

(Obviously I could iterate through all subsites and set it manually ..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There an easier way to do this using the SharePoint API:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
publishingWeb.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/mycustom.master";
publishingWeb.CustomMasterUrl.SetInherit(true, true);
publishingWeb.Update();
```

Comment: thats the kind of simple anwser I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Old answer I know, but I would like to point out for future observers that this doesnt actually work. The CustomMasterUrl property of the PublishingWeb class is readonly.

Comment: An alternative way would be to use the publishingWeb.CustomMasterUrl.SetValue(string, bool) method to set the value and force the subwebs to inherit the Master Page.

Comment: how can this be done in CSOM? web.CustomMasterUrl is a string there

Comment: @WaldekMastykarz  
is there a equivalent for CustomMasterUrl.SetInherit in CSOM?

Comment: @vignesh did you manage to get this working in CSOM v15? `SetInherit` doesn't seem to be available there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best we can do is something like the following in the FeatureActivated method.

```
foreach (SPWeb site in siteCollection.AllWebs) 
{
  site.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/mycustom.master";
  site.CustomMasterUrl ="/_catalogs/masterpage/mycustom.master";
  site.Update();
  site.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SetMaster(SPWeb web, string masterpagePath, string custommasterpagePath) 
{
    web.CustomMasterUrl = masterpagePath;
    web.MasterUrl = custommasterpagePath;
    web.Update();

    foreach(SPWeb child in web.Webs) 
    {
        try {
            SetMaster(child, masterpage, custommasterpage);
        } 
        finally
        {
            if(child != null) child.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Call this passing the SPSite.RootWeb, and specifying the path to your master pages. It'll recurse over all the sites below that rootweb in the site collection (i.e. all of them!)

Note that you may need to consider whether the sites below use [different master pages](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/30/feature-receiver-to-apply-master-pages/) as [this can cause problems](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/22/setting-a-site-master-on-a-publishing-site-breaks-meeting-workspaces/), particularly with Meeting Workspaces, but possibly others.

You may also need to consider [storing the original master pages details in the property bag](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/06/24/setting-the-master-page-of-a-team-site-with-a-feature/) for the web so you can restore them later (e.g. feature deactivation)

And you may wish to [make sure that themes are turned off](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/17/programmatically-apply-a-default-theme-in-sharepoint/) and don't interfere with your look and feel.